# Manpages in developer mode shell on Chrome OS?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, chroot, google-chrome-os

On most unix systems, the command man usually shows a manpage for the following command. However, in both the Chrome OS shell in developer mode and the xfce linux shell installed through chroot, man does not work. Are there manpages for chrome OS?

Comment: Maybe you need to install some `manpages` package.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Couldn't find one.

Answer (score 0):

in xfce you can execute this command to install the man command and basic man pages:

```
sudo apt-get install man-db
```

then enter your password when sudo prompts you

this command will find more content packages:

```
apt-cache search manpages|grep manpages
```